# How to turn off create new track popup?

Tags: animation, godot, gdscript

I know this might be an unusual question but is there any way to turn off this annoying popup?

[image]

I made a custom animation player which sets a different track for a custom property

i.e. if I press add key of `custom_property` it will add the key of `position` instead,
and in doing so the track of `custom_property` is never made, so every time I add a key of it this pops up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh never mind I found it,
it was in the `Editor>Editor Settings...>Animation`

and deselect the Confirm Insert Track

[image]